# How to pass more arguments to Sqlbulkcopy notifyafter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am invoking a notifier while doing the sqlbulkcopy. As of now I am only printing the number of rows that are written to the DB. I would like to print other arguments like the DB name, current timestamp, etc.. can someone please let me know how to do this.

Comment: If you're referring to the SqlRowsCopiedEvent there is no other info the event args: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlrowscopiedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can't pass more data to the event handler. You would have to handle the event internally in your class/method and in there raise a custom event with the extra details you require.

Comment: Basically i would like to call a common method that takes filename, numberofrows loaded, status as arguments and updates a common table where we track the number of rows loaded into the database and its timestamp with status as processing... SqlRowsCopied notifier takes 2 arguments one as object another as eventargument.. eventargument can't be used.. is it possible to pass extra information as first argument as object?

Answer (score 1):

You can't provide arguments to the event handler, but you can use a delegate that captures as much local information as you like:

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(...)) {
    string database = "myDatabase";
    bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += (o, e) => {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Time: {0}, database: {1}, rows copied: {2}", 
            DateTime.Now, database, e.RowsCopied
        );
    };
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(...);
}
```

You can make this generic by wrapping it in a method and using the method arguments instead of local variables. You can also wrap `SqlBulkCopy` itself and create your own event with a custom `EventArgs`, but for the information you're adding, that doesn't seem to be worth it.